# ignore security dependency if environment is set to local or dev

Tags: python, fastapi

I have this dependency in my REST endpoint definition

```
@api_router.post(path="/request")
def post_request(
    request_body: RequestBody,
    access_token: AccessToken = Security(validate_roles, scopes=["user.access"])
)
```

This `validate_roles` function has its own dependency

```
async def validate_roles(
    security_roles: SecurityScopes,
    access_token: AccessToken = Depends(decode_token)
)
```

The thing is that I want to skip this validation when the environment is `local`, so I won't need to decode the token. `validate_roles` is function, that I cannot change.

What can I do?

I tried this

```
async def env_aware_validate_roles():
    if settings.ENVIRONMENT.lower() != 'prod':
        return lambda: AccessToken(
            roles=["user.access"], 
            iss="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0",
            aud="<app id>"
        )
    else:
        return validate_roles

 Security(env_aware_validate_roles, scopes=["user.access"])
```

But it did not work. I also tried to call `env_aware_validate_roles()` but then I get the error

```
<coroutine object env_aware_validate_roles> is not a callable object
```

Comment: Make `env_aware_validate_roles` a `def`, not `async def`.

Comment: You could also `mock.patch` the `decode_token` to not do anything in the local environment for a surgical change.

Comment: changing to `def` just made it stop validation altogether - now even `validate_roles` does not do anything.

Comment: @AKX by mock.patch you mean for testing or something?

Comment: Not necessarily. There's nothing saying you couldn't have e.g. an application startup hook that just patches that function depending on settings.

Comment: oh! I have found solution using `dependency_overrides`

Comment: Excellent! Please write a self-answer then so others can see it :)

Answer (score 0):

As a solution I went with approach using [overrides](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/)

```
if settings.ENVIRONMENT.lower() != "prod":
    app.dependency_overrides[validate_roles] = lambda: AccessToken(
        roles=["user.access"],
        iss="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0",
        aud="<app id>",
    )
```

It seems to be working fine.